# Order of magnitude in Absolutely convergent Fourier series

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

There is a question in "An introduction to harmonic analysis" by Yitzhak Katznelson.

**Problem:** Let $f\in A(\mathbb T)$($\mathbb T$ denotes the torus), i.e. $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}|\hat f(n)|<\infty$, $f$ is real valued and monotonic in a neighborhood of $t_0\in\mathbb T$. Show that $$|f(t)-f(t_0)|=O((\log|t-t_0|^{-1})^{-1}) \text{ as }t\rightarrow t_0.$$

I try to compute the Fourier series of $f(t)-f(t_0)$ directly and use Abel summation. However, it seems to me that monotonic makes nonsense. Can someone tell me how to solve the problem? Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the result absolutely summable Fourier coefficient implies the Fourier series converges uniformly?  Start estimating.

Comment: Yeah, I think this result can be derived from the definition of the absolutely summable coefficients. In fact $|\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\hat f(n)e^{int}|\leq \sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty|\hat f(n)|\rightarrow 0$, as $m\rightarrow \infty$, this estimate does not depend on $t$.